# How to set child div background color based on position in parent with a linear gradient

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, linear-gradients

I'm trying to make a horizontal div with a vertical div positioned over it based on a score prop passed in.

Component:

```
const ScoreBar = ({ score }) => {
    const left = `${score * 10 - 10}%`;

    return (
        <div className="ScoreBar">
            <div className="Scorebar-Horizontal">
                <div className="Scorebar-Vertical" style={{ left: left }}>
                    {score}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

CSS:

```
.ScoreBar {
    width: 250px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: rgb(243, 239, 239);
    border-radius: 4px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

.ScoreBar .Scorebar-Horizontal {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 25%;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, red, yellow, green);
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.ScoreBar .Scorebar-Vertical {
    width: 10%;
    height: 120px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    background: inherit;
    opacity: 1;
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: black;
}
```

The positioning is working just fine.

However, I want the vertical div to inherit its parents' gradient color based on its position in relation to its parent.

In other words: if the score is 1, the vertical div will be positioned to the left of the parent element, but I also want it to inherit the red color, and as the score increases and the vertical div moves across the horizontal div, I want it to inherit its parents' color all the way to the rightmost side where it would be green.

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I am just mentioning HTML and CSS here. Using these inline CSS you can control your requirement. Please ask if any clarification needed..

```css
.ScoreBar {
    width: 250px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: rgb(243, 239, 239);
    border-radius: 4px;
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px 20px 10px 20px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column-reverse;
}

.ScoreBar .Scorebar-Horizontal {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 25%;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, red, yellow, green);
    border-radius: 3px;
}

.ScoreBar .Scorebar-Vertical {
    width: 100%;
    height: 120px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    background: inherit;
    opacity: 1;
    border-radius: 3px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-weight: 700;
    color: black;
}
.value{
    position: absolute;
    width: 10%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
        <div class="ScoreBar">
            <div class="Scorebar-Horizontal">
                <div class="Scorebar-Vertical" style="clip-path: polygon(50% 0, 60% 0, 60% 100%, 50% 100%);">
                    <span class="value" style="left:50%">60</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

[image]